# Long s in pdfLaTex

Tags: latex, pdflatex, typesetting

I am trying to mock an antique writing style in LaTex (standard Overleaf with pdfLaTex) and I need to include the old "long s" letter (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_s). Using the ſ symbol produces the `LaTeX Error: Unicode character ſ (U+017F)` error.

Here's a minimal example with my actual header, thank you for any suggestion:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,titlepage]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\begin{document}

Here is a ſimple example

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you set on using pdflatex? Overleaf also offers xelatex or lualatex, both of which can deal with unicode characters by default (remove the `fontenc` package if you switch to xe/lualatex)

Comment: No, I am only using pdflatex because it is the default option, but any other compiler is fine, as long as I get a pdf output.

**N.B.**: I removed my previous comment as I did a gross oversight, I am sorry. I changed to xelatex and disabled the `fontenc` package as you say, and now Overleaf displays the "long s" correctly. Thank you, problem solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to use unicode characters in latex is to switch to an unicode aware engine such as lualatex or xelatex. In overleaf, you can switch to them in the sidebar of your project.

If you use one of these engines, you should remove the `fontenc` package.

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,titlepage]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\begin{document}

Here is a ſimple example

\end{document}
```

[image]